# Triggering A Package Version Update In Separate Azure DevOps Repo and Build Pipeline

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, nuget-package

I have two Git repos in Azure DevOps.  For the sake of simplicity, let's call them LibRepo and AppRepo.  When LibRepo has a pull request completed, the build pipeline is kicked off and a new NuGet package version is pushed to Artifacts.  That said, I'd like to be able to automatically create a new commit in AppRepo so that the package references use the new version of LibRepo and kicks off a new build for AppRepo. If possible, I'd like that commit to contain the same commit message as the package.  Any and all responses would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it with the pipeline script by following below steps:

1. Check for the main branch content.
2. Update the versions.
3. Make sure the build is successful.
4. Later update the version number.

Check these blogs([blog1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops), [blog2](https://systemadminspro.com/automatic-version-number-management-with-azure-devops/)) for more insights